# Laravel: Variable not being passed from controller to view

Tags: php, html, laravel-5, drop-down-menu, eloquent

using Laravel 5.6.28 my route on web.php file looks like this:

```
Route::get('kitysoftware/besttrades', 'SectorsController@besttradesview');
```

My controller with *bestrasdeview* function:

```
class SectorsController extends Controller
{
     public function besttradesview()
     {
        $sectors = DB::table('Sectors')->get();
          foreach ($sectors as $sector) {
            echo $sector->SectorName;  
           }
       //passing variable sectors1 to my view (is = $sector) 
      return view('besttradesview', ['sectors1' => $sector]);
      }}
```

My view *Bestradesview.blade.php* is:

```
<form method="GET">
<div class="selectsector">
<Select class="selectsector" name = "sectors">
<option value="{{ sectors1 }}"></option> 
<!-- test#2: <option value="{{ $sectors1->sector[] }}"></option> -->
<!-- test#3: <option value="{{ $sectors1->sector }}"></option> -->
</form>
</select>
```

- And i get this error: *Use of undefined constant sectors1 - assumed
  'sectors1' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP)*
- When testing #2 commented line instead i get another error: *Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException (E_UNKNOWN)
  Cannot use [] for reading*
- When testing #3 commented line without [] i get another error: *Use of undefined constant sectors1 - assumed 'sectors1' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP)*

Probably it's pretty simple but it's driving me nuts because i can't see why the variable is not passing to the view. 
I know it's reading my table because if i remove the last *return view* call line on my controller, it echoes out all the values from my *SectorName* column, but i want it on a select dropdown menu.

I have been reading the docs, forums and watching laracast videos without luck. Any insight or just pointing me out to where to learn the proper sintax solution will be appreciatted. 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to populate the select options from the query. If that's the case, your loop is in the wrong place.

Take the loop out of the controller method, and pass the `$sectors` collection directly to the view.

```
public function besttradesview()
{
    $sectors = DB::table('Sectors')->get();
    return view('besttradesview', ['sectors1' => $sectors]);
}
```

Then loop in the view to output the options.

```
<select class="selectsector" name="sectors">
    @foreach($sectors1 as $sector)
        <option>{{ $sector->SectorName }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

I assumed you wanted some text in the option. If you use the sector name as the option text it will also be used as the option value by default. If you want to use something else for the value, it would be like this, for example:

```
<option value="{{ $sector->id }}">{{ $sector->SectorName }}</option>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's working now. I was wondering the right place to place that foreach, i thought to keep only html in my views. But got it working changing it as per your suggestion. Makes more sense.

Comment: You're welcome. Generally, keeping html in the view is the right way to look at it. But most template systems like blade have looping structures for this kind of thing. It isn't really like putting your business logic in the presentation layer, though. It's just kind of necessary for rendering a template with repeated elements effectively.

Answer (score -1):

Change,

```
return view('besttradesview', ['sectors1' => $sector]);
```

To,

```
 return view('besttradesview', ['sectors1' => $sectors]);
```

Notice the `s` in `$sectors` (`$sectors = DB::table('Sectors')->get();`) and in the actual view, it should be `$sectors1` not just `sectors1`.

You also need to loop through actual sector:

```
@foreach ($sectors1 as $sector)
    <option>{{ $sector->SectorName }}</option>
@endforeach
```

Also, I would definitely suggest creating a model for your `Sectors` table rather than using the `DB::` facade. You should make use of the *M* in *M*VC.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However changed the s and still same error: Use of undefined constant sectors1 - assumed 'sectors1' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP)
I thought it supposed to use the variable coming from the foreach, not the one with the query.
I have a model called Sectors as well. I thought this was the proper way to connect with that model

Comment: @gallo2000sv please see my edit: '*and in the actual view, it should be $sectors1 not just sectors1.*'

Comment: Thanks again. I tried again after changing the s and putting $sectors1 in the view, and getting: Trying to get property 'sector' of non-object

Comment: @gallo2000sv you also need to loop through the actual sectors in the view. Check the my update `@foreach`.